# PHP Namespaces: If I'm not going to need to redeclare already taken functions do I need them?

Tags: php, namespaces, php-5.3

I'm wondering, that if my functions don't have similar names, do I need to use namespaces?

*plus I can't get the grips of importing all namespaces from a specific folder...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm wondering, that if my functions don't have similar names, do I need to use namespaces?

No.

However, namespacing does offer more benefits than avoiding namespace collisions, it also forces you to maintain good directory and file structures which makes your files easy to find, and an intuitive approach to determining parent/child relationships.

For example:

```
// Zend/Translate/Adapter.php
class Zend_Translate/Adapter {}

// Zend/Translate/Adapter/Csv.php
class Zend_Translate_Adapter_Csv extends Zend_Translate_Adapter {}
```

As you can see, classes relating to similar objects are logically grouped together, and as the above code snippet demonstrates, signifies possible parent/child relationships. One caveat, even though a  directory may contain a class file along with a sub-directory, it is not guaranteed that the files within the sub-directory will extend the file.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are approaching this question from the wrong perspective. Sure, you can avoid using namespaces if you know you have unique function names. But that is a very short sighted approach and doesn't take into account how complex the application is, how it is structured, etc.

As mentioned by Mike, if you are going to be using frameworks like Zend or Symfony or any other code heavy on Object Orientated Programming, then I would strongly recommend using namespaces. Let's say you want to include a class from a great PHP package. Without namespaces, you will have no assurance there will not be any conflicts.

Additionally, new frameworks like Symfony 2.0 REQUIRE you to use namespaces. So you better get used to it.

Comment: I'm not talking about frameworks whatsoever, I'm referring to organizing my projects into (perhaps) more manageable components/sub-components.

Comment: @Fike Frameworks are only part of my answer. I felt that mentioning them was relevant to this discussion.